# Need help importing a variable from a components file to an app.js file(React)

Tags: reactjs

Super rookie question. So I'm making this little click game that allows you to change the number displayed on the home page with button clicks.

Here's the component file I want to export the Result var from.

---

```
import React from "react";
import "./Wrapper.css";



const Wrapper = (props) => {

    var Result = 0;
    
  function addCount() {
    Result++;

    console.log("increased");
    console.log(Result);
  }

  function subtractCount() {
    Result--;

    console.log("decreased");
    console.log(Result);
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {props.children}
      <button className="btn btn--alt" onClick={addCount}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={subtractCount}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

===

And here's the app.js file I want that same var imported to so it can fielded into the  element with this.state.

---

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper";
import Title from "./components/Title";
import Count from "./components/Count";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    CountNum: 0,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <Title>Click Counter</Title>
        <Title>Count:</Title>
        <Count>{this.state.CountNum}</Count>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I thought it would get picked up automatically but no luck.

Comment: You need to pass the state `CountNum` and the `setState` function to the `<Wrappper/>` component.

Comment: Why not use callback instead of export?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to put your Result in parent component's state
Then pass the necessary setState functions to child component

It is more react way.

Simply create a function that updates the state 'result' in parent then pass those functions to child component and execute when needed

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the **CountNum** as a prop and also a function to update it (eg. setCountNum). Also you need to replace `var Result = 0;` with `var Result = props.CountNum;` or **CountNum** value will become 0 again on each render.
Here's an example.

**In App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Wrapper from "./components/Wrapper";
import Title from "./components/Title";
import Count from "./components/Count";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    CountNum: 0,
  };

 setCountNum = (val) => {
   this.setState({CountNum: val})
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper setCountNum={this.setCountNum} CountNum={this.state.CountNum}>
        <Title>Click Counter</Title>
        <Title>Count:</Title>
        <Count>{this.state.CountNum}</Count>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Your Component:**

```
import React from "react";


export const Wrapper = (props) => {

    var Result = props.CountNum;
    
  function addCount() {
    Result++;

    console.log("increased");
    console.log(Result);
    props.setCountNum(Result)
  }

  function subtractCount() {
    Result--;

    console.log("decreased");
    console.log(Result);
    props.setCountNum(Result)

  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {props.children}
      <button className="btn btn--alt" onClick={addCount}>
        +
      </button>
      <button className="btn" onClick={subtractCount}>
        -
      </button>
    </div>
  )}
```

Also if you want, you can update the structure of your code and have all the states in one component only.

Comment: This is what I went with and it works! Easy to read too.

Comment: That's great 

Comment: So I tried replacing var Result = 0; with var Result = props.setCountNum; but it returned NaN in the <Count> component instead of a number. This isn't crucial but do you have any pointers on this?

Comment: My bad. It will be var Result= props.CountNum. I wrote it correct in code but while describing I wrote setCountNum by mistake. I've updated my answer. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

And by the way, You should not use var variable. Better to use let / const variables. When use let or const?

Let if you want to change its value in the future. Your example for a variable is "Result".

Const if you do not change the variable by reassigning it.

Have a good coding! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.count);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Wrapper
          count={this.state.count}
          onChangeCount={(count) => this.setState({ count })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Wrapper = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => props.onChangeCount(props.count + 1)}>+</button>{" "}
      <span>{props.count}</span>{" "}
      <button onClick={() => props.onChangeCount(props.count - 1)}> - </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can use this idea for your application. Just pass the count & function as props and update the state from inside the wrapper component

Answer (score 0):

Full functional component example. Feel free to ask :)

```
import React from "react";
import {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App () {
  //CountNum initial value is set to 0; setCountNum is function that updates the CountNum values;
  const [CountNum, setCountNum] = useState(0);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {/* setCountNum is being passed from the parent component App to the child component Wrapper */}
      <Wrapper setCountNum={setCountNum}/>
      {/*if the counter changes this would update*/}
      {CountNum}
    </div>
  )
}

//{setCountNum} is the same as props.setCountNum; props is a default naming for a argument in React
//export default function Wrapper(props){...} if you did this you would have to call props.setCountNum() 
//export default function Wrapper( {setCountNum} ) if you did this you would have to call setCountNum() "(destructuring objects) "
//However, if you want to call the function you would have to call props.setCountNum() instead of setCountNum()
export default function Wrapper( {setCountNum} ) {
  const incremFunc = () => {
    setCountNum(previousValue => previousValue + 1)
  } 
  const decremFun = () => {
    setCountNum(previousValue => previousValue - 1)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={incremFunc}>Increment</button>
      <button onClick={decremFun}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```